# C# Loading a xml file from the current directory?

Tags: c#, xml

I use the line below in my C# winform app, this works great but occasionally if the program is being run from the command line I get an error that the `config.xml` file cannot be found. This is because the 'working directory' is different (I think), I need to say "load config.xml from current directory", how would I do this?

```
docXML.Load("config.xml");
```

Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "config.xml");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    string Path = "";
    string Filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Filename");
```

> for loading from current directory

```
   Path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Filename);
```

> for loading from Base directory

```
    Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + Filename;
```